# CKEDITOR change h1..3 tags to h4..6 tags

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I only want to allow h4, h5, and h6 header tags in my editor. When getData() is called, I'd like h1, h2, and h3 tags to be filtered and chaged to h4, h5, and h6 respectively. I've tried to apply a filter, but that doesn't seem to be allowed.

```
CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].on('getData', function (e) {
    var filter = new CKEDITOR.htmlParser.filter({
        elements: {
            h1: function (e1) {
                e1.name = 'h4';
            },
            h2: function (e1) {
                e1.name = 'h5';
            },
            h3: function (e1) {
                e1.name = 'h6';
            }
        }
    });
    filter.applyTo(e.data.dataValue);
}, null, 12);
```

Above is the code I've written. Any useful methods I'm missing to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this use case just by modifying [format headers](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_config.html#cfg-format_h1).
E.g. you could write your code like:

```
CKEDITOR.config.format_h1 = { element: 'h4' };
CKEDITOR.config.format_h2 = { element: 'h5' };
CKEDITOR.config.format_h3 = { element: 'h6' };
```

Be aware that if your users have access to `source` mode it won't work. In that case, I think the best you can do is adding custom filter transformation. You can find out more about this feature reading [CKEditor docs](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_filter.html#method-addTransformations).